# How to route a request to a specific VM in Azure Cloud Services

Tags: routes, azure-cloud-services

I am trying to route a request to a specific VM in a service pool in Azure Cloud Services. The load balancing software distributes requests uniformly to machines in a pool. Once I receive the request I'd like to route it to the specified machine in the request.

Comment: Azure cloud services is paas services, and should not be able to route to the specified machine in the request.

Comment: Why is there such a demand?

Comment: I'm looking to implement machine level diagnostics

Comment: You can log on to the machine to check the IIS log or ApplicationLog, and check the EventView.

Comment: Has your problem been solved? Is my comment helpful to you?

Comment: I think my best option is to make an internal endpoint. i'm trying to create something more accessible to OCEs than logging on to the machine.

Comment: If you find a solution, you can send it out to help more forum users.

Comment: I think I can route the request via an internal endpoint. I need a way to get the service pool's instances, once I know the URI, a new process on the machine listening for internal requests can receive traffic. Fingers crossed.